# Why is WSH giving me the "expected ;" error?

Tags: windows, javascript, wsh

Im trying to get my feet wet with some WSH. I thought it was going to be easy, but it's really a nightmare...

contents of registry.js >

```
Set shell = WScript.CreateObject('WScript.Shell');
strRegValue = 'HKLM/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/ProductID';    
strPID = shell.RegRead(strRegValue);    
WScript.Echo strPID;
```

This is a code snippet to read a registry value. Maybe you can see what'
s wrong with it because I sure cant!

Comment: you might want to have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760169/i-am-having-trouble-learning-javascript-any-suggestions/1761170

Comment: what is useful at that link? I know javascript.

Comment: I didnt write this code I copied it from another site. I didnt realize WSH was using javascript or actually JScript. In either case I don't know the JScript API for doing windows shell related functions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about trying this way:

```
var shell = WScript.CreateObject('WScript.Shell');
// my version of windows does not have the regkey you initially specified
strRegValue = 'HKLM\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\CommonFilesDir';    
strPID = shell.RegRead(strRegValue);    
WScript.Echo(strPID);
```

Comment: so, I've made three changes:
1) keyword var instead of set (it is jscript, isn't it?)
2) backslash characters needs to be escaped in string literals 
3) parenthesis were missing from the print statement

Comment: one more tip: if you're planning to print this out to the console, instead of a message box, use cscript.exe as your script host (the default is wscript.exe, eg: cscript.exe registry.js)

Comment: thanks for fixing that. I grabbed that WSH snippet from some website. I should have known better =/ But how do I do the cscript thing you suggested. I am using CMD

Comment: these scripts (.js or .vbs) don't get just executed on their own, they need a host process or interpreter. On windows this is called the script host, and there are two kind: wscript.exe and cscript.exe. Cscript stands for console script while wscript is the windows script host. Unfortunately wscript is the default one, so if you're planning to use stdin/stdout features, you are going to get "invalid handle" errors. However you can explicitly set your script host by just typing it in at your command prompt, and giving your script file name as its parameter. check out cscript.exe /? for more.

Comment: perfect! so can I use these in place of batch files?

Comment: and how can i get console input to the script file using cscript?